# Cannot change fields value with redux-form

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

I'm having troubles initializing a form from state.

Long story short, I'm using an `Input` compoenent, with a `Value` prop. When inspecting my app, I can see that the value is correctly initialized.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import * as styles from './Input.css';

interface InputProps {
    type: 'Text' | 'Password' | 'Email';
    placeholder: string;
    name: any;
    value?: any;
}

export default class Input extends React.Component<InputProps, {}> {
    render() {
        return (
            <div className={styles.inputContainer}>
                <input
                    type={this.props.type.toLowerCase()}
                    className={styles.input + ' ' + styles[`input${this.props.type}`]}
                    placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
                />
                <i />
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Now, my problem is, if I keep it this way, my inputs are empty, even though the Input component is initialized with a value. The only way to fill my inputs is to add this:

```
value={this.props.value}
```

In this case, the inputs are filled with data from state, BUT they also become readonly: I cannot edit their content.

How can I prefill my inputs with state data while keeping them editable ?

Comment: Check how you should pass props into Field component http://redux-form.com/6.6.3/docs/api/Field.md/

Comment: I tried this, but the behaviour is really weird: I can focus on the input, I can type in (Altough the value itself won't change, it's stuck on the value fetched from the props), and if I add an onChange method, it triggers every time I type something in.

Comment: It's because it is meant to be triggered every time you type. You want to update your state every time, so `redux-form`  `disptach` an action on every input. It seems like overkill at first, but meant to work this way.